# How to avoid exception during inserting data to database

Tags: database, exception

I use dataset' Insert() method to insert data to database.Like:

```
 public void InsertData()
 {
    ATableAdapter a = new ATableAdapter();
    a.Insert(//some parameters);  //step 1: OK
    BTableAdapter b = new BTableAdapter();
    b.Insert(//some parameters); //step 2: throw exception
    ....
 }
```

When running step 2, the program throws a exception and stop running the following functions,
but in database, there is a dummy record that generated in step 1,
how can i avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap both steps in a Transaction.

See [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx).

You will need to enlist the commands in the transaction.

Comment: This thread might be useful: http://www.devnewsgroups.net/adonet/t54792-tableadapters-transactions-again.aspx